# How change index in multiindex dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing, multi-index

I have a multiindexed pandas data frame like:

```
            col1        col2        col3        col4        col5
ix  iy                                                        
0   14       True          1           1          1           1
    25       True          1           1          1           1
    27       True          1           1          0           1
    28       True          1           1          1           0
    43       True          1           1          1           1
1   12       True          1           1          1           1
    38       True          1           1          1           1
2   0        True          1           1          0           1
    1        True          1           1          1           0
```

How I can change the index by adding a constant value to them? For example `ix + 5` and `iy + 10`:

```
            col1        col2        col3        col4        col5
ix  iy                                                        
5   24       True          1           1          1           1
    35       True          1           1          1           1
    37       True          1           1          0           1
    38       True          1           1          1           0
    53       True          1           1          1           1
6   22       True          1           1          1           1
    48       True          1           1          1           1
7   10       True          1           1          0           1
    11       True          1           1          1           0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recreate new `MultiIndex`, here with tuples and [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html):

```
L = [(a + 5, b + 10) for a, b in df.index]
df = df.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(L, names=df.index.names))

print (df)
      col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
ix iy                              
5  24  True     1     1     1     1
   35  True     1     1     1     1
   37  True     1     1     0     1
   38  True     1     1     1     0
   53  True     1     1     1     1
6  22  True     1     1     1     1
   48  True     1     1     1     1
7  10  True     1     1     0     1
   11  True     1     1     1     0
```

Another idea with [`MultiIndex.set_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html):

```
df.index = df.index.set_levels(df.index.levels[0] + 5, level=0)
df.index = df.index.set_levels(df.index.levels[1] + 10, level=1)
print (df)
       col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
ix iy                              
5  24  True     1     1     1     1
   35  True     1     1     1     1
   37  True     1     1     0     1
   38  True     1     1     1     0
   53  True     1     1     1     1
6  22  True     1     1     1     1
   48  True     1     1     1     1
7  10  True     1     1     0     1
   11  True     1     1     1     0
```